# Syntax error while executing java command in python script

Tags: java, python, semantic-analysis

i want to execute following command in a python script

```python
    java -cp lib/*:esalib.jar clldsystem.esa.ESAAnalyzer "$1" "$2"
```

but i'm getting a syntax error due to the '*' and ':' in the path of jar files. How else could i do it?

Comment: How are you executing the python script and the java command normally?  '*' expands if its run through the shell, and not all python exec options do it by default (you'll see `shell=True` in docs)

Comment: How are you trying to execute it?  `os.system`?  `subprocess.Popen`? `commands.some_api_that_should_not_be_used`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use subprocess library.
I hope it helps you:  [Subprocess management](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 0):

i used the subprocess library and its working now.:)
Here is how i did it

```
    import shlex,subprocess
    x='java -cp "lib/*:esalib.jar" clldsystem.esa.ESAAnalyzer "$1" "$2"'
    args=shlex.split(x)
    p=subprocess.Popen(args)
```